# Re-training a tensorflow model

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, named-entity-recognition

I am training a customized Named Entity Recognition **(NER)** model using **NeuroNER** which is written using tensor-flow.I am able to train a model and its performing well but when i am re-training it on new observation for which it showing incorrect result it correcting them but its **affecting/forgetting some previous observation** for which it showing correct results.

I want **online re-training**.I tried using stanfordNLP , Spacy and now tensor-flow.please suggest a better way to achieve the desired goals.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a misunderstanding behind this question. When you train a model you adjust a set of parameters, sometimes millions of them. Your model will then learn to fit this data.

The thing with Neural Network is that they may forget. It sounds bad but is actually what makes it really strong: it learn to forget what is useless.

That is, if you retrain you should probably:
- run just a few epoch, otherwise the model will overfit the new dataset thus forgetting everything else
- learn on a bigger dataset i.e. past+new data, would ensure that nothing is forgotten
- maybe use a larger setup (in terms of hidden layers size, or number of layer) since you cannot indefinitely hope to learn more with the same setup.

I'm not expert in online training but that's not something you can expect without effort. It is in fact quite hard to do in practice. It's far from being the default behavior when you "just" continue training.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I will try this approach.